# I renamed a database, but ColdFusion is still looking for the old name

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We are creating a new version of our website. So, I made a copy of the current database and rename it to a new name. When I try to load the new site I get the following error

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid object name 'name1.dbo.table'.
```

The datasource in the CFAdmin is pointing to the new DB, and the site's source code is using the new datasource. I've deleted the datasource that pointed to the old DB anyways.

```
CF Data Source Name: name2
Database:            name2
```

I can't find anything in the site's source referring to either of the DBs, all queries are executed through stored procedures. (all of which now point to name2 instead of name1) This is a fresh install of ColdFusion, so there can't be anything in the CFAdmin that is somehow pointing at the old DB instead of the new one. Other than that I have no idea what is causing this issue. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are confident that ColdFusion is looking at the right database, then the next place to check is stored procedures that have a three-part reference that mentions the old name explicitly. This might turn up false positives, depending on what name1 really is, but it's a start:

```
SELECT p.name, m.definition
  FROM sys.procedures AS p
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON p.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE m.definition LIKE N'%name1%';
-- put old name here --------^^^^^
```

It could also be a function or trigger or some other module, so maybe wise to expand the search:

```
SELECT o.name, o.type_desc, m.definition
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON o.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE m.definition LIKE N'%name1%';
-- put old name here --------^^^^^
```

And you may also want to widen the search to other databases on the instance, too, you know, just in case. :-)

Comment: I had already checked all the SPs that used the table in question, but they don't use the 3 part references. There is however a sister DB that has triggers to update this table that I had forgotten about. This looks to be the source of my problem.